# Problems with PHP when trying to create big array

Tags: php, memory, arrays

Here is my code, which creates 2d array filled with zeros, array dimensions are (795,6942):

```
function zeros($rowCount, $colCount){
    $matrix = array();
    for ($rowIndx=0; $rowIndx<$rowCount; $rowIndx++){
        $matrix[] = array();
        for($colIndx=0; $colIndx<$colCount; $colIndx++){
            $matrix[$rowIndx][$colIndx]=0;
        }
    }
    return $matrix;
}

$matrix = zeros(795,6942);
```

And here is the error that I receive:

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 35 bytes)
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Since you are creating a zero filled array in memory, I assume that you want to run some operations on this. In that case, why don't you use a datastore like Redis? It will hold huge data with small overhead to php. And you can run operations with negligible performance pitfall.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As a quick calculation, you are trying to create an array that contains :

```
795*6942 = 5,518,890
```

integers.

If we consider that one integer is stored on 4 bytes *(i.e. 32 bits ; using PHP, it not be less)*, it means :

```
5518890*4 = 22,075,560
```

bytes.

OK, quick calculation... result is "*it should be OK*".

But things are not that easy, unfortunatly :-(

*I suppose it's related to the fact that data is stored by PHP using an internal data-structure that's much more complicated than a plain 32 bits integer*

Now, just to be curious, let's modify your function so it outputs how much memory is used at the end of each one of the outer `for`-loop :

```
function zeros($rowCount, $colCount){
    $matrix = array();
    for ($rowIndx=0; $rowIndx<$rowCount; $rowIndx++){
        $matrix[] = array();
        for($colIndx=0; $colIndx<$colCount; $colIndx++){
            $matrix[$rowIndx][$colIndx]=0;
        }
        var_dump(memory_get_usage());
    }
    return $matrix;
}
```

With this, I'm getting this kind of output *(PHP 5.3.2-dev on a 64bits system ; `memory_limit` is set to `128MB` -- which is already a lot !)* :

```
int 1631968
int 2641888
int 3651808
...
...
int 132924168
int 133934088
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
```

Which means each iteration of the outer `for`-loop requires something like 1.5 MB of memory -- and I only get to 131 iterations before the script runs out of memory ; and not 765 like you wanted.

Considering you set your `memory_limit` to `128M`, you'd have to set it to something really much higher -- like

```
128*(765/131) = 747 MB
```

Well, even with

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '750M');
```

it's still not enough... with `800MB`, it seems enough ;-)

But I would definitly not recommend setting `memory_limit` to such a high value !

*(If you have 2GB of RAM, your server will not be able to handle more than 2 concurrent users ^^ ;; I wouldn't actually test this if my computer had 2GB of RAM, to be honest)*

The only solution I see here is for you to re-think your design : there has to be something else you can do than use this portion of code :-)

*(BTW : maybe "re-think your design" means using another language PHP : PHP is great when it comes to developping web-sites, but is not suited to every kind of problem)*

Answer (score 5):

The default PHP array implementation is very memory-intensive. If you are just storing integers (and lots of them), you probably want to look at [SplFixedArray](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php). It uses a regular contiguous memory block to store the data, as opposed to the traditional hash structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should try increasing the amount of memory available to PHP:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '32M');
```

in your PHP file.