# memory issue when trying to create an array

Tags: php

I have a form my company uses to create some files on the fly based on the input.  I have a text area`$fileString` and they can enter file names followed by a hard return.  I take that and create an array, `$list`.  What i'm trying to do is if they enter in the text area two file names like this:

```
item1

item2
```

that it will create an array that contains 6 values, not two, so like this:

`$genList = array(item1_f, item1_b, item1_i, item2_f, item2_b, item2_i);`

I am getting this error though when I run my code:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes) in /home/dcolor/public_html/dev/create.php on line 18
```

Line 18 is:

```
array_push($genList, $list[0] . "_f", $list[0] . "_b", $list[0] . "_i");
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Code below

```
    $fileString = $_POST['fileList'];
    $unique = $_POST['unique'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $generateArray = $_POST['generateArray'];
    $list = explode("\r\n",$fileString);

    if ($generateArray == "yes") {      
        if ($size == "5x7inimpos") {
            $genList = array();
            while (!empty($list)) {             
                array_push($genList, $list[0] . "_f", $list[0] . "_b", $list[0] . "_i");                    
            }
        }
        print_r($genlist);
    }
```

Comment: My first guess is that `while(!empty($list)) {}` is an infinite loop.

Comment: [Number 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313893/problems-with-php-when-trying-to-create-big-array?rq=1) in sidebar for related..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (!empty($list)) {             
        array_push($genList, $list[0] . "_f", $list[0] . "_b", $list[0] . "_i");                    
}
```

`$list` never gets emptied, you never get out of the while loop.

You just want to iterate over the list:

```
foreach($list as $element)
{

    array_push($genList, $element . "_f", $element . "_b", $element . "_i");                    

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is

```
while (!empty($list)) {             
    array_push($genList, $list[0] . "_f", $list[0] . "_b", $list[0] . "_i");                    
}
```

Because `$list` will never be empty and thus causing an endless loop. PHP tries to push more and more elements into `$genList` until the memory limit exceeds.

You probably want to remove the element in the loop.

Comment: I don't understand why the `$list` will never be empty.  If the original text area only had 4 file name values, `$list` would contain 4 array values.  It would go empty after the 4th go through, correct?

Comment: No, because in the While loop you are not removing anything from list. You are reading the value in $list[0] an infinite amount of times :). 

In this case you could just iterate over the list like in moonwave99's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an infinite loop to me. Why would `$list` ever become empty?

```
while (!empty($list)) {             
    array_push($genList, $list[0] . "_f", $list[0] . "_b", $list[0] . "_i");                    
}
```

Therefore, you will allocate memory with `array_push` until you hit your [256MB] memory limit.